# train_test_split not working as expected on stratified data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to split my data in a stratified way. I think `train_test_split`from `sklearn` doesn't work the expected way on imbalanced datasets.

Here is an example:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from collections import Counter

y = [7]*2 + [1]*100 + [2]*3 + [3]*3 + [4]*6 + [5]*100 + [6]*2 + [8]*2
xtrain, xtest = train_test_split(
        y, stratify=y, test_size=0.2, 
        shuffle=True, random_state=42
    )

print(Counter(xtrain))
#Counter({1: 80, 5: 80, 2: 2, 4: 5, 8: 2, 3: 2, 7: 2, 6: 1})

print(Counter(xtest))
#Counter({5: 20, 1: 20, 6: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})
```

Classes 1 and 5 are distributed the expected way. However, classes that are underrepresented are not well distributed. Classes 6,2,3,4 are well distributed but not 8 and 7. Am I missing something to do this split correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually think it does work. You just have too few samples in some classes for it to be statistically accurate.

I tried the following

```py
y = [7]*200 + [1]*10000 + [2]*300 + [3]*300 + [4]*600 + [5]*10000 + [6]*200 + [8]*200
```

the output is correctly:

```
>>> Counter({1: 8000, 5: 8000, 4: 480, 2: 240, 3: 240, 6: 160, 7: 160, 8: 160})
Counter({1: 2000, 5: 2000, 4: 120, 2: 60, 3: 60, 6: 40, 7: 40, 8: 40})
```

best regards
- ga97dil

Comment: That's an issue for very unbalanced datasets, yes. But I need to have these samples in my test set, even if my model only trained on one item of this class.

Comment: I get what you mean now. Sadly i cannot find anything about the functionality you need in the sklearn documentation. Two very naive approaches that come to mind would be: 1. before calling the function split all elements that have a too low representation off and add them afterwards to your ```xtrain```; 2. Search for a random state so that all elements with a  too low representation are in ```xtrain```.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you are missing anything. Stratify tries to maintain the representation of each class during the split. The only issue here is the sample size is not large enough for you to see a full reflection in the test size.

You could solve this by increasing the sample size for 8 and 7.